# Reading XML at LINUX Startup

Tags: xml, linux, boot

I have an executable of LINUX. When, executed it reads an xml file to fill dynamic variables and modify my display accordingly.

I wanted to start this executable file just after user login in RHEL6. For which i wrote a script, made it executable and added it on System->Startup Application.

Problem here is, when i boot Linux, the exe runs, without reading dynamic data from xml file.
I thought that its problem of my script, but, if I run/execute my script after booting process is over, the script runs fine.
My doubt is, is there any xml service/engine which i should enable before my exe is executed or any other method to read xml and exe both at booting up of linux. 
What should be the sequence of commands I have to execute.

Comment: How does the program locate the XML file? If it is done through environment variables, that may be the issue.

Comment: that's actually not clear, as i only have the executable of it. If there is any way of knowing this from exe only, please share. In case its through environmental variable, how can i know which variables to set and how to set them.

Comment: even if you only have the executable, you should have the documentation. (Or are you blindly using a binary you were given with no information about it? That seems rather dangerous).

Comment: no documentation is not provided. i agree it may be dangerous, but thats my requirement so have to use it